# Boolean value set symbol

Tags: symbols, logic

I want to define boolean function in my latex document but can't find the symbol I'm looking for. My function gets an input of A and renders a true or false value to it. I have added an image to make it clear. I am looking for the symbol **L** [image: This 'L' is the symbol I am looking for]

Comment: `\mathbb{L}` (`amsfonts` package)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I could accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Werner I tried that. No success.

Comment: @VSZM: Look at Table 299: Math Alphabets in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). Symbols matching your style is given as supported by [`amsfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts) using `\mathbb`.